# Change color on a specifik <a> tag that have same id as the div tag if div tag fields are filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, html5-video

I have two of `<a>` links that have `date-id` that is the same of `div` tags `id`,  when the div tags fields have values set in it. The `<a>` links should change color to green. I wonder how I can do this,

my `<a>` menu look this:

```
 <div class="wrapper">   
                    <div class="parent">  
                        <a data-id="6" data-counter="0" href="#" class="box navigation"></a>
                        <p>1</p>   
                    </div>  
                    <div class="parent">
                        <a data-id="7" data-counter="1" href="#" class="box navigation"></a>
                        <p>2</p>
                    </div>
</div>
```

and my div tags with fields look like this:

```
<div class="wizard-step2" id="6">
    <p>1. how are you? <span class="b">Betyg:&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <select class="Grade" id="selectetListItems" name="selectetListItems"><option value="">n/a</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    </select></span></p>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <textarea class="Comment" cols="20" id="selectstyle3" name="Comment" rows="2">
</textarea>
    </div>
    <input class="QuestionID" id="SelectedQuestions" name="QuestionID" type="hidden" value="18" />
</div>

<div class="wizard-step2" id="7">
    <p>1. how are you? <span class="b">Betyg:&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <select class="Grade" id="selectetListItems" name="selectetListItems"><option value="">n/a</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    </select></span></p>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <textarea class="Comment" cols="20" id="selectstyle3" name="Comment" rows="2">
</textarea>
    </div>
    <input class="QuestionID" id="SelectedQuestions" name="QuestionID" type="hidden" value="18" />
</div>
```

What I have done is a ajax post on a button click and inside the post I need this functionality that if the div tag with id 6 has its fields filled change the  link with same data-id to green:

This is my on click:

```
$("#next-step").click(function () {
            var $step = $(".wizard-step2:visible"); // get current div step
            var validator = $("form").validate(); // obtain validator
            var anyError = false;

            var Comment = $step.find(".Comment").val();
            var QuestionID = $step.find(".QuestionID").val();
            var Grade = $step.find(".Grade").val();

            var data =
                {
                    Comment: Comment,
                    QuestionID: QuestionID,
                    Grade: Grade
                };
            $.post('@Url.Action("AnswerForm", "AnswerNKI")', data, function () {

                if (Comment != null && Grade > 0) {

               $(".box").css({ "background-color": "green" });

                }

            });
```

If you check inside my `Post` I just did a test changing the `.box` to green, this changes all `<a>` links to green but that is wrong. It's inside that if statement I need help.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that, in this example, `$(this)` will be the `$('#6')` `div` element, and *also* that your `if` condition evaluates correctly:

```
if (Comment != null && Grade > 0) {
    $('a[data-id="' + this.id + '"]').css({ "background-color": "green" });
}
```

Assuming, as in your posted example, that the click is on `$('#6')`, this retrieves the `id` from `this` (no real need to wrap in a jQuery object in this case), and concatenates that into the selector to become, effectively, `$('a[data-id="6"]')` and then changes that link to a `background-color` of `green`.

References:

- [`[attribute="value"]` attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: the problem is that click is on  var $step = $(".wizard-step2:visible"); // get current step

Comment: Ill edit my post example and give the full code maby you understand then :)

Comment: Why is it a problem that it's on `$('.wizard-step2:visible')`? That still has the `id="6"`, and that should still relate directly to the `$('a[data-id="6"]')`. What am I missing?

Comment: I am looking in to it beacuse its not changing color on the link

Comment: Try adding a `console.log($('a[data-id="' + this.id + '"]').length)` (or even just `console.log($('a[data-id="' + this.id + '"]'))` to verify it's selecting the right element) into your `if` statement. And possibly `console.log(Comment != null && Grade > 0)` just before the `if` statement, which should evaluate to either `true` or `false`, to give an idea of what's happening.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean your `if` statement? Then that's beyond the scope of this question, I'm afraid. Though I'd suggest `console.log(Comment, QuestionID, Grade);` and see what's returned. Or possibly `console.log(data['Comment'], data['QuestionID'], data['Grade']);`.

Comment: I got the if statement working, its executing '$('a[data-id="' + this.id + '"]').css({ "background-color": "green" });' but when I check the console.log its length is 0 and undefined

Comment: Everything is working now I had to do a minor change: `$('a[data-id="' + QuestionID + '"]').css({ "background-color": "blue" });`

Comment: Well, I'm glad to have helped (even if only to get you started) =)

Comment: Thanks! The only part left is to make sure the color stays even if you close the browser or rerun the web application

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`$(".box[data-id='" + ID-that-needs-changing + "']").css({ "background-color": "green" });`

This basically looks for the `box` class with a `data-id` equal to the the ID you're getting after the post.

Comment: that doesnt work beacuse <a> links and <div tags> are generated by foreach loops, it can be any kind of id. the ID that are set on those attributes are from the ids in the database tabels.